# Trimming a String with whitespace

Tags: regex, perl

I would like some help parsing a string of someones name. I would like to take the string and remove it so that only the first name will be in the string.

Suppose I have a name like this

```
Mr. John Doe
John Smith.
```

In both cases I would like to only get the first name of the string and delete all other characters.

So for both strings after they have been parsed will on have `John` in them

I was wondering if there was a way to do this problem with regex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do it. Not without annoying some people because you've mangled their name. You can't distinguish between John Paul Doe (first name “John”, middle name “Paul”, last name “Doe”), John Joseph Brown (answers to “Joseph” or “Joe” but only ever uses “John” on government forms), and John Paul Smith (first name “John Paul” and hates to have it shortened).

Go read [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Then go read it again, and this time accept that, yes, 95% of the population of the world have 
a completely different idea of what a name is from yours. (80% if you're Chinese.)

The most you can do is to truncate whitespace and maybe a few “safe” prefixes like “Mr” — and I wouldn't do even that (if people bothered in to write “Mr”, they presumably like to have it there).

```
s/^\s+//; s/\s+$//;     # trim whitespace at each end
s((\s+))(               # trim embedded whitespace
    $1=~/[^\x{a0}]/ ?   # breakable?
    " " : "\x{a0}")ge;
```

Comment: This post is highly exaggerating the problem. It also assumes the OP has a world-wide audience. It should instead be edited to perhaps ask more about the audience and the variety of formats and describe the caveats much more softly **especially 95% ???** I don't even know 20% or even 5% that fit that rule.

Comment: @George: By default, I target a worldwide audience but am aware that people from the US don't bother. Note that you will find such Johns and not-Johns in the US (even if most are like Mr Doe).

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, your name is in the first capturing group $1.

```
^(?:Mr\.|Mrs\.)?\s*\b([^\s]*)\b.*$
```

See it [online here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2tpit)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple regex that will match both cases

```
/^(?:\w+\.)?\s*(\w+).*$/
// $1 = John
```

You can build it up like this:
`\w+\.` at least one word character followed by a dot (for the name prefix)
`(\w+\.)?` the group can appear once or not at all
`(?:\w+\.)?` the group is non capturing (we don't need it)
`^(?:\w+\.)?` ^ signals the beginning of the entire string (so this group is the first thing in it)
`^(?:\w+\.)?\s*` this prefix group can be followed by any number of spaces(or none)
`^(?:\w+\.)?\s*(\w+)` than follows the group for the name (which consists of at least one word character)
`^(?:\w+\.)?\s*(\w+).*$` finally `.*` matches the rest of the characters until the end of the string `$`

Comment: Clever! Anything with a dot is an abbreviation! :)

Answer (score 0):

How many different formats do you want to accept?

Here's one that should work for the two you posted:

```
/(?<=((Mr\.|Mrs\.)\s+)?)([a-zA-Z]+)/
```

Comment: and just add all your other prefixes in that list.

Comment: This will not work. Number one, not all (perhaps not any) versions of Perl support variable repetition inside lookbehind, and number two, This will match Mr as the first name.

Comment: This is not working for me [http://regexr.com?2tpj3](http://regexr.com?2tpj3). How should your lookbehind with optional group work? Assuming there is no Mr. then it should be empty and your last part will match any word, even the last name.

Comment: @George is there any Version of Perl that will? As I now only .net does support variable length look behind.

Comment: @stema: Edited my comment, I did not want to make too much a claim and be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work

```
my $nameFull = 'Mr. John Doe';
my $nameFirst = $1 if $nameFull =~ /(?:\s|^)(?!(?:mr|mr?s|miss|dr|prof)(?![a-z]))([a-z]+)/i;
```

Explained:

`/`...`/i` Start and end of a case insensitive regex

- `(?:\s|^)` Make sure that we are either at a whitespace character or the beginning of the string.
- `(?!`...`)` Make sure this won't match at the start of the first name

  - `(?:mr|mr?s|miss|dr|prof)` List of abbreviations (the `r?` means optional `r` so this will match `Ms` and `Mrs`)
  - `(?![a-z])` Make sure that there are no more letters right after the abbreviation, because `drake` is a name that starts with `dr`
- `(`...`)` Capture this to `$1`

  - `[a-z]+` As many letters as there are in a row. Assume at least one.

Comment: I am sorry, I tested it now and indeed it is working. I don't understand what happens here in your complicated regex with your lookaheads, but it delivers the first name in this example.